# How to avoid Default selection on long press in android Kitkat 4.4?

Tags: java, android, webview

Hello Developers,
                 i am working with Btwebview here on long press we are avoiding the default selection functionality on long press and giving our own.The overriding of long press method is working perfectly till android 4.3 but with 4.4 the defalut selection also coming with actionbar.Below i am mentioning the sample code-

```
public class BTWebView extends WebView implements TextSelectionJavascriptInterfaceListener, OnTouchListener, OnLongClickListener,DragListener    {
.......
public BTWebView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.ctx = context;
        this.setup(context);
    }
    protected void setup(Context context)
        {
        this.setOnLongClickListener(this);
        this.setOnTouchListener(this);

         }
```

and on long press

```
   @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v)
    {
       ......
    return true;  
    }
}
```

Here after overriding the long click and return value as true so it avoid default selection till 4.3 so please tell me how to avoid either the complete default selection or atleast avoid the action bar comes on long press .thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for KitKat and above proposed by Ravi Saini works to prevent the default selection interface to appear. However, return true for ACTION_UP event prevents fling gestures for scrolling the contents vertically quickly, so the use of WebView seems unnatural. I added *isInSelectionMode()* condition to prevent this, now fling gestures work fine, except when in selection mode. The code from [WebViewMarker GitHub project](https://github.com/naoak/WebViewMarker) with my change is as follows (in TextSelectionSupport.java module, onTouch() method):

```
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        if (!mScrolling) {
            endSelectionMode();
            //
            // Fixes 4.4 double selection
            // See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20391783/how-to-avoid-default-selection-on-long-press-in-android-kitkat-4-4
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        mScrollDiffX = 0;
        mScrollDiffY = 0;
        mScrolling = false;
        //
        // Fixes 4.4 double selection
        // See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20391783/how-to-avoid-default-selection-on-long-press-in-android-kitkat-4-4
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT && isInSelectionMode()) {
            return true;
        }
        break;
```

Greg

Comment: This tricks solve the problem for 4.4, but Lollipop, the problem is not solved. Can anyone give any solution for Lollipop?

Answer (score 3):

i found the solution for this question here on github ,it is-

```
 if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
        {       
              if(!mScrolling){
                  mScrolling = false;
                  endSelectionMode();
                  return false;
              }

              mScrollDiffX = 0;
              mScrollDiffY = 0;
              mScrolling = false;

              // Fixes 4.4 double selection
              return true;
        }
```

here also you have to return the true,after that the default selection will not come .

Answer (score 0):

If the onLongClick() method isn't getting called and the long press in the WebView is enabling the user selection (i.e. copy, cut, paste etc) then you could try the user-select CSS property

```
user-select:none;
```

Which will surpress that behaviour, although not sure if this will still fire the long click listener, or whether the WebView will continue to inherit the click events.